# Add contents of Array List to a JSON Array: Java

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have an Array List called *getFields*:

```
ArrayList getFields = new ArrayList(uniqueFields);
```

This array list logs out the following:

```
[{"warehouse":{"editableField":"false"}}, {"documentNo":{"editableField":"true"}}]
```

I need to convert *getFields* into a JSON Array called *jsArray*, so I have done this:

```
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray();
jsArray.put(getFields);
```

jsArray logs out the following:

```
[[{"warehouse":{"editableField":"false"}},{"documentNo":{"editableField":"true"}}]]
```

The problem is, I do not want jsArray to have a nested array (i.e. I don't want it to have double square brackets). I want it to be like this:

```
[{"warehouse":{"editableField":"false"}},{"documentNo":{"editableField":"true"}}]
```

How can I convert getFields into jsArray without the double brackets? Have tried converting to a string but then I get backslashes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: invoke `jsArray.put` for individual elements in your `ArrayList getFields`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getFields.forEach(jsArray::put);  // java 8+
```

You need to iterate on `getFields` and put the elements one by one.

---

```
// java 8 or below
for (int i = 0; i < getFields.size(); i++) {
    jsArray.put(getFields.get(i));
}
```